# Typescript compile error Property 'some' does not exist on type 'LodashArrayWrapper<any[]>'

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am trying to use lodash in my typescript program to do the following:

```
 var atLeastOneCategoryMissingEntities = _(this.list)
            .pluck("items")
            .map((m:any) => {
                return _.pluck(m, "id");
            })
            .some((arr) => {
                var val = _.difference(arr, this.anotherList);
                return val.length === arr.length;
            });

list:[
{
  category:{
      name: "",
      id:""
  },
  items:[{
      name:"",
      id:""
 }]
}
]
```

and anotherList is an array of strings.

I get a compilation error "Property 'some' does not exist on type 'LodashArrayWrapper'."

Answer (score 0):

```
var atLeastOneCategoryMissingEntities = _(this.list)
        .pluck("items")
        .map((m:any) => {
            return _.pluck(m, "id");
        })
        .value()
        .some((arr) => {
            var val = _.difference(arr, this.anotherList);
            return val.length === arr.length;
        });

    list:[
{
  category:{
  name: "",
  id:""
},
items:[{
  name:"",
  id:""
  }]
 }
]
```

Typescript definitions for lodash do not allow to use `.some` on type 'LodashArrayWrapper'. So using `.value` converts it into an Array and then you can use `.some` on it and typescript compiler will not complain anymore.